# ASP.Net Core Razor pages: how does <form class="needs-validation"> actually invoke client-side validation?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, bootstrap-4, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I'm working with a ASP.Net Core 3.1 web application.

If a Razor page has a form with `class="needs-validation"`, then client-side validation is invoked for the fields in that form.  Specifically, `jquery-validation-unobtrusive` gets called when the user clicks "Submit".

Q: How exactly does this occur?  What "magic" links the HTML class "needs-validation" to the"validate()" Javascript code?  Is there some CSS file somewhere that defines this linkage?

Q: Is "needs-validation" a Bootstrap class?  Or is it standard HTML5/CSS3?  Where/how is it defined?

These are some of the links I've found, but I still don't understand the linkage between class "needs-validation" invoking the validation code:

- https://wakeupandcode.com/validation-in-asp-net-core-3-1/
- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/
- https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-validation-unobtrusive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, asp.net core application use [jQuery Unobtrusive Validation](https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-validation-unobtrusive) and https://jqueryvalidation.org/ plugin to achieve the client side validation. JQuery Unobtrusive Validation parses the data- attributes and passes the logic to jQuery Validation, effectively "copying" the server-side validation logic to the client. You can display validation errors on the client using tag helpers as shown here (without the `class="needs-validation"`):

```
    <form method="post">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Movie.Title" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Movie.Title" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Movie.Title" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Movie.Description" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Movie.Description" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Movie.Description" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        ....
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

The `class="needs-validation"` is used for custom Bootstrap form validation messages (use HTML5 form validation), then, it will based on this class selector to find elements and validate the data. Check the [Bootstrap Validation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#custom-styles) to learn how it works and how to use it.